# Cannot get information about current certificate (cannot access to x509_st and x509_cinf_st structures)

Tags: openssl, libcurl

I'm trying to get information about current certificate with curl_easy_getinfo (..., CURLINFO_TLS_SSL_PTR, ...) and SSL_get_peer_certificate(...) methods.

I can get x509_st pointer as SSL_get_peer_certificate return value but I cannot get x509_cinf_st pointer (as cert_info field).

I have found much information about "opaque" structures in 1.1.0 version but I have not found information which accessors can I use for getting x509_cinf_st object and its fields.

Comment: Yes, OpenSSL 1.1.0 made many formerly open structures opaque. The 'cinf' (TBS) part of X509 can no longer be read, or set, as a structure, but all the fields _in_ it can be read or set, some by preexisting (oldstyle) X509_get/set/add_ routines, some by newstyle X509_get[0m]/set1/add1_ routines. Look in the list at https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/ .

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer